# Banning a model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, scope

I have several models that `belong_to :status`.

Statuses are:

- Active
- Hidden
- Banned

I have scopes set up for each of the statuses, and they apply to users and several other content models, but let's take `User` for example.

Out of habit, I write `User.find(15)` or `User.all` or `User.last(5)` or `@category.users`

I don't think there should be any reason to change that. In fact, call me selfish, but I don't *want* to change that. I feel like I should be able to handle this sort of task at a higher level, and avoid having to retype over and over again:

- `User.active.where(...)`
- `User.active`
- `User.active.last(5)`
- `@category.users.active`

That just seems unconventional. Unfortunately, these models are used throughout many instances, so I would like a way, maybe at the model level, to prescreen for banned or hidden models. For example, removing banned instances from the `all` scope, but as well as scopes like "last" or when the model is queried in general. Or if an instance is called specifically that falls withing the banned or hidden scope, it raises a record not found. I'd still like to be able to access these instances through their individual scopes (eg `User.banned` or `User.hidden`) but I'd rather *that* be the extra typing, rather than the queries that are most commonly used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define some scopes

```
default_scope joins(:status).where(:status => {:state => :active})
scope :hidden, unscoped.joins(:status).where(:status => {:state => :hidden})
```

Comment: Wow thanks! I might have to try it tomorrow as the wife broke her laptop and has commandeered my machine to watch Netflix.

Comment: Quick note, using the join made the model read-only, so I just used `where(:status_id => 1)` It was `default_scope` that saved my life, thanks